# Search for "special" characters in FILE CONTENTS using Mac Finder

Tags: mac, search, finder

I have looked everywhere for the answer to this and I can't find it...  I have found lots of examples of searching for **file names** with special characters, but none searching for **file contents** with special characters.

I'm trying to search for all .css files on my Mac that contain the exact text `height: 4in;`

BTW, the OS is MacOS Ventura 13.6, in case that matters.

So in the Search box, I type `kind:css` then I click the `+` button and add a `contents` parameter, then type `height: 4in;` in that box.  It finds nothing.  (To be clear, if I type **only** `height` or `4in` it finds plenty of files.  I want to narrow it down to files containing exactly `height: 4in;`)

I assume the `:` and `;` is screwing it up.  How do I get around that?  I've tried escaping them with / or \ but neither of those work.

What do I need to do to search for special characters **in the contents of files** in Mac Finder?

Comment: Have you tried quotes `"` around the search string?

Comment: Thanks!!!  That worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

User DavidPostill just posted the answer in a comment above.

Put quotes around the search string and it works.  If I search for `"height: 4in;"` instead of `height: 4in;` it works.

Interestingly enough, this seems to work even when you're searching for something with `"` in it.  I just tested it on some other code that has double quotes in it, and I was able to find the exact string, so long as I put double quotes around the entire search string.  Cool!